# Getting string in Protected Function Android

Tags: android

Basically I have a stand alone class, which does not use Activity OR Service.
A function in the class starts a new Authenticator.

I have a string in the strings.xml file, which I want to access
Looking for the best method

Example code

```
class MyConnection(){

 String username;
 String pwd;
 String strurl;
  public MyConnection(String usernameIN, String pwdIN, String urlIN){
      this.username = usernameIN;
      this.pwd = pwdIN;
      this.strurl = urlIN
  }
 public void
 URL url = null;

 try {
    url = new URL(this.strURL);
    URLConnection urlConn = null;
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()){

         protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()(
                // I want my vars from strings.xml here
                return new PasswordAuthentication(strUsername, strPwd.toCharArray());
         }
    });
  urlCOnn = url.openConnection();
  //Rest of the code, including CATCH
}
```

I passed the vars through into the class BUT how do I access them When I set the PasswordAuthentication.  OR Can I access them direct from strings.xml ???

Answer (score 0):

How do you create an instance of the `MyConnection` class?

It should be through an Activity or a Service, right?

Then when you create it, pass the current Activity

```
public class MyConnection {

    private Activity activity;

    public MyConnection(Activity a) {
        this.activity = a;
    }

    //....

    private void method() {
        activity.getResources().getString(R.string....);
    }
}
```

**edit:** I did not see you already had a constructor. Then add a parameter to the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `final` modificator to your `MyConnection()` constructor's parameters, this way you can use them as parameters in the call to `PasswordAuthentication()`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass a `Context` instance to your class or individual methods. The `Context` instance can be an instance of `Activity` or `Service` or anything else which is a subclass of `Context`. You can then use this to access system resources:

```
class MyConnection
{
    private final Context context;

    public MyConnection( Context context )
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    .
    .
    .
    public void someMethod()
    {
        String str = context.getResources().getString ( R.string.myString );
    }
}
```